# Trouble with javascript subtraction

Tags: javascript, math, subtraction

I'm working on a simple subtraction problem, but unfortunately it keeps returning `NaN`

Here is the function

```
   function subtraction(a, b) {
        var regexp = /[$][,]/g;

        a = a.replace(regexp, "");
        b = b.replace(regexp, "");


        var _a = parseFloat(a);
        var _b = parseFloat(b);

        return _a - _b;
     }
```

And here is how I'm calling it.

```
txtGoodWill.value = subtraction(txtSellingPrice.value, txtBalanceSheet.value);
```

The numbers that get submitted to the function are ONLY Currency (IE: `$2,000` or `$20`, etc)

Now I know that I cannot subtract numbers with a `$` or a `,`, but I can't for the life of me figure out why they are getting evaluated in the equasion.

Comment: `b - b.replace(regexp, "");` should probably be `b = b.replace(regexp, "");` -- is that typo just here, or in your original code?

Comment: sorry, that's a typo.. I've fixed the question.

Comment: could the problem possibly have to do with "null" values?  If so, how would I compensate for that?

Comment: I decided to NIX the subtraction function and just do it in the main function... seems to have worked.  Not sure why I couldn't get the function to work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression only matches if a `$` is directly followed by `,`. Use `/[$,]/g` instead to match all occurrences of either of the two characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `var regexp = /[$,]/g;` (both the `$` and `,` inside the same set of square brackets).